# Late return value in C++

Tags: c++

Today I did a funny mistake in my C++ code. I have a function with two arguments of type `std::vector<int>::iterator&` (`i` and `j`). Iterators should point to same vector. Function should return sum of two numbers in the vector, and move both iterators forward to j+1th position of vector:

```
int exp_func_add::evaluate(vector<int>::iterator& i, vector<int>::iterator& j) {
    int result = *i + *j;
    ++j;
    i = j;
    return result;
}
```

First I wrote this code:

```
int exp_func_add::evaluate(vector<int>::iterator& i, vector<int>::iterator& j) {
    ++j;
    i = j;
    return (*i+*j); // <====== Oops !
}
```

We know that `return` statement returns control to caller. My question is why C++ standard does not define a late value return semantics? Let's call it `late_return` keyword:

```
int exp_func_add::evaluate(vector<int>::iterator& i, vector<int>::iterator& j) {
    late_return *i+*j; // Hold return value but don't go back 
                       // to the caller until leaving scope
    ++j;
    i = j;
}
```

This question may get hundreds of downvotes (not constructive, blah blah). Though I would like to ask some questions:

1. Is there a way to simulate this behavior using macros or any other tricks?
2. Do this deserve an implementation or to be considered as a feature in next c++ standard?
3. Are there programming languages implementing similar feature?

Comment: Why would anyone consider making this a language feature (and not just in C++) when a) it's not "the most common operation by far" and b) it's stupidly easy to implement using existing language features? You 'd have to take up a substantial cost to specify and implement the feature so that... developers can *sometimes* save one line of code?

Comment: I don't see any benefit in doing this.

Comment: The amount of code required for the obvious work-around (which is the one you give in your first code example) is so small that introducing an entire new keyword for this seems unjustified. Keep in mind that every new keyword is one token less that can be be used freely for user-defined identifiers, and it is one more source of potential compiler bugs.

Comment: @Jon I don't know why exactly people implement language features and what is procedure of standard definition. But I assume a feature may be a part of standard iff it does not break something and it makes sense. Anyway I think I'm only guy on the planet who likes this :P

Comment: @soroush: First of all, [read this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/01/12/57985.aspx) to familiarize yourself with the concept of "-100 points". The idea is that every language feature is by definition a burden: the committee has to specify it, compiler writers have to implement it, developers have one more thing to remember -- and that's not even counting the possible interactions between N language features. A feature has to offer *way* more benefit than this to justify itself (think about how you had to implement lambdas before C++11).

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the link. I see that adding `late_return` does not solve a real problem, does not introduce a (really) new feature of language. And even brings more serious problems: Adding a new keyword breaks backward compatibility (old sources may have variables named `late_return`). The only statement I can't accept is what @Mark says in below answer: `No, because it adds complexity without any clear benefit over the existing idiom.`

Comment: Pascal's mechanism of returning values works exactly like your proposed `late_return`: `function myfun : integer; begin myfun:=5; {calculations} end;` returns 5

Answer (score 3):

- Is there a way to simulate this behavior using macros or any other tricks?

Not really, though your first code sample is fairly idiomatic C or C++ code.The "assign a value to "result", and then have 'return result' as the last statement of the function is avery common pattern.

- Do this deserve an implementation or to be considered as a feature in next c++ standard?

No, because it adds complexity without any clear benefit over the existing idiom. It'd add a whole bunch of edge cases to the language, too. Functions can have more than one return statement, so how so you handle multiple late_return statements? First one wins? Last one wins? Throw an exception? What about a code path that includes late_return and return?

- Are there programming languages implementing similar feature?

The closest thing I can think of is constraints languages or logic languages like Prolog, where the "result" is produced as soon as all of the data necessary to produce it has been provided.

Comment: Multiple `late_returns` are allowed and last one wins. In the case of  `return` and `late_return` combination, always `return` wins. That's my C++ :D One may decide to restrict use of `return` and `late_return` in a function to reduce complexity.

Comment: @soroush Too much to remember for such a small benefit (`T result = ...; ...foo... return result;`).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to simulate this behavior using macros or any other tricks?

Yes, and you said it yourself: define a variable called `ret` and return it at the end. That's only one line more and it's a lot more clear what is going on when you get to the end of the function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you are essentially looking to do something like this:

```
return *i + *(++j, i=j, j-1);
```

The problem with this is that **i** may already be changed by the time we get to it. It will not necessarily (won't?) evaluate this statement left-to-right.

As other posters have mentioned this really doesn't provide any added benefit to the language, except maybe to save a line or two of code. That being said, it sounds to me like you want something like a **reverse** [**comma operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

It doesn't exist, but the idea has been brought up [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++/PTur1GAWLKw) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/LycQVRm43i0).

All in all, I think it adds significant complexity in a situation where it really is not needed. I don't see this as a bad question because it is always good to try and better understand how/why things work. I just don't think this particular use case warrants it.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. `*i` can be evaluated before or after `i=j`.

Comment: @LBg I don't think you read my answer: _The problem with this is that `i` may already be changed by the time we get to it. It will not necessarily (won't?) evaluate this statement left-to-right._